# Appropriate reaction to accepted answers containing inaccurate information?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I just posted a comment to [Interfacing microcontroller and mains via a relay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/interfacing-microcontroller-and-mains-via-a-relay). The accepted answer makes inaccurate (and imo possibly dangerous) claims. Should/Could I do anything more than insert a comment to that affect on the accepted answer and down-vote it?

Answer (score 3):

No, you acted accordingly.

There's no claim that an an excepted answer is inherently "correct." It is simply the answer that the original author thought was most helpful to them. If an information in any post is incorrect, correct it. That's why there is an edit function on this system. If you do not have the reputation to edit, you can comment (to request the changes) and down-vote. If the information is dangerous (as in it should never have been published), you can also flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: bear in mind that commenting requires 50 rep and downvoting requires 125, whereas flagging only requires 15. I would also add that *adding a competing correct answer which also points out flaws in the accepted answer* takes ZERO rep and is always the preferred course of action.

Answer (score 1):

Answer seems fine to me. It's a company app note vs. personal experience.

Comment: Also, the app note is about maximizing lifetime, not necessarily safe operating guidelines.